# Client application update

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I'm developing client-server application by using .Net, C#, WCF, WPF. And now I need to implement client applications update process (client dll's). Could someone suggest some good pattern for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Click-Once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) makes updating the applications on client computers relatively painless.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635103/how-to-basic-tutorial-to-write-a-clickonce-app
- [Guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications.aspx)
- [Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c19523/ClickOnce-Deployment-in-NET-Framework-20.htm)
- [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227123(v=VS.80).aspx)